# Non-translation association schemes duality

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory, association-schemes

In his [thesis](https://users.wpi.edu/%7Emartin/RESEARCH/philips.pdf) (1973), P. Delsarte defines a duality construction for association schemes. Nevertheless, this duality construction works only if some special *regularity* condition is satisfied. I find the condition hard to grasp. It seems just like a technical assumption in order to make it work. A particular case is the duality of translation association schemes associated to abelian groups (Theorem 2.9), which works always and is described also in various other texts such as [this](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecgodsil/pdfs/assoc2.pdf) or [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669808002448).

Is the general construction of Delsarte really more general or is it true that actually any association scheme that has this kind of dual must be a translation association scheme?